# FastAPI Numeric Validation

Tags: validation, fastapi, pydantic

I'm writing a FastAPI based applicaiton and I am having problems with validation - I've got two methods that should have validation:

```py
@app.put('/camera/focus')
def set_focus(value : Annotated[int, Query(gt=0)]):
    queue_set('camera', reader.camera, 'focus', value)
```

and

```py
@app.put('/serial')
def set_serial(value : Annotated[str, Query(min_length=5)]):
    queue_set(None, reader, 'serial', value)
```

If I try to create an error with the following calls:

http://{{base_url}}:8000/camera/focus?value=-1

This should not validate because the focus value is <0

http://{{base_url}}:8000/serial?value=XXX

This should not validate because the value query parameter is too short.

However neither of these are giving validation errors and the methods are executing; I can't find any reason for this.  Do I need to turn on FastAPI validation?

P.S.

I'm not sure if it is important but I'm starting uvicorn in code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

args = parse_cmdline()

if args.log_level is not None:
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s', level=name_to_level.get(args.log_level.lower(), logging.NOTSET))
else:
    try:
        logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
    except:
        #fallback
        print("could't set logging from logging.conf file")
        logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s', level=logging.ERROR)
        
reader = make_reader(ScannerType[args.scanner_type.upper()], args.sim)
uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=args.port, log_level=args.log_level.lower())
print('done')
```

This is done because I need to setup and configure hardware before starting the uvicorn server.

Comment: you can use conint https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#arguments-to-conint

Comment: What is your FastAPI version?

Comment: I ran this code and it gets me error 422 if I pass incorrect input values.
Check whether you reloaded app after making the changes

Comment: Yes I did - I put in a print in the method to check this and it still didn't validate

Comment: FastAPI version is 0.92.0

Comment: I would recommend that you upgrade to the current version of the FastAPI (0.104.1) if possible.

Comment: Are you actually calling this as a PUT endpoint or as a GET endpoint (i.e. directly in your browser?)

Comment: @NeilBenn the version is below the recommended 0.95.1+ for `Annotation` to work properly as stated in the documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#additional-validation
Can you please update the version and try again?

Comment: Will do I used pip to install fast API on a Debian box and this is what it gave me.  Do we have a pip repos with the latest version on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#alternative-old-query-as-the-default-value

> Previous versions of FastAPI (before 0.95.0) required you to use Query as the default value of your parameter

I see that you have 0.92.0

I would recommend you to upgrade FastAPI version to the current release

Comment: Thanks - do you know a pip repos that has the current release on it as 0.92.0 is the version that the default pip repos gives.

Comment: @NeilBenn https://pypi.org/project/fastapi/ here is a newest one version